# Symfony: How to handle 2 forms in the same action?

Tags: php, symfony

I have two forms that i want to handle in the same action, actually the first one works pretty good, but the other form doesn't work. This is my action code :

```
 /**
     * @Route("/webmaster/gestProf/{idprof}",  defaults={"idprof": 0},name="gestProf")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function gestProfAction(Request $request)
    {
        $session = new Session();
        $session->start();

        $em=$this
            ->getDoctrine()
            ->getManager();
        $repository = $em->getRepository("CNAMCMSBundle:profil");
        $profils = $repository->findAll();


        foreach ($profils as $prof) {
            $id = $prof->getId();
            $libelle = $prof->getLibelle();

        }
        $profil = new profil();
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($profil, array('csrf_protection' => false))
            ->add('id', 'text', array('attr' => array('maxlength' => '255', 'placeholder' => 'Nouvel Identificateur', 'id' => 'id_prof')))
            ->add('libelle', 'text', array('attr' => array('maxlength' => '20', 'placeholder' => 'Nouveau Libellé', 'id' => 'libelle')))
            ->add('idprof', 'hidden', array('mapped' => false,'attr' => array('maxlength' => '20', 'placeholder' => 'Nouveau Libellé', 'id' => 'libelle')))
            ->add('Edit', 'submit', array('attr' => array('class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-block rounded_btn', 'id' => 'login_btn',
                'style' => "width:6vw;height:5vh;padding:0px 0px; position:relative;left:5vmin;top:1vmin;font-size:2vmin;")))
            ->getForm();
        $profile = new profil();
        $form2 = $this->createFormBuilder($profile, array('csrf_protection' => false))
            ->add('id', 'text', array('attr' => array('maxlength' => '255', 'placeholder' => 'Nouvel Identificateur', 'id' => 'id_prof')))
            ->add('libelle', 'text', array('attr' => array('maxlength' => '20', 'placeholder' => 'Nouveau Libellé', 'id' => 'libelle')))
            ->add('Ajouter', 'submit', array('attr' => array('class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-block rounded_btn', 'id' => 'login_btn',
                'style' => "width:6vw;height:5vh;padding:0px 0px; position:relative;left:5vmin;top:1vmin;font-size:2vmin;")))
            ->getForm();
        if ($request->request->has('form')) {
           $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $data = $form->getData();
            $idprof = $form->get('idprof')->getData();
            $id = $data->getId();
            $libelle = $data->getLibelle();
            $em = $this
                ->getDoctrine()
                ->getManager();
            $repository = $em->getRepository("CNAMCMSBundle:profil");
            $profil = $repository->find($idprof);
            if ($id !== Null) {
                $profil->setId($id);
                $em->merge($profil);
                $em->flush();
            }

            if ($libelle !== Null) {
                $profil->setLibelle($libelle);
                $em->merge($profil);
                $em->flush();
            }
        }
    }
        if ($request->request->has('form2')) {
            $form2->handleRequest($request);
           // $id2 = $request->request->get('id');
           // $libelle2 = $request->request->get('libelle');
            if ($form2->isSubmitted() && $form2->isValid()) {
                $data2 = $form2->getData();
                //$idprof = $form->get('idprof')->getData();
                $id2 = $data2->getId();
                $libelle2 = $data2->getLibelle();
                $em=$this
                    ->getDoctrine()
                    ->getManager();
               $profile->setId($id2);
               $profile->setLibelle($libelle2);
                $em->persist($profile);
                $em->flush();
            }
        }

        return $this->render('CNAMCMSBundle:Default:gestProf.html.twig', array('profils'=>$profils,
            'form'=>$form->createView(),
             'form2'=>$form2->createView()

        ));
    }
```

And this is their implementation in Twig :

```
{{ form_start(form, { attr: {novalidate: 'novalidate'} }) }}
                            <section class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9" style="position: relative; left: 5vmin;top: 6vmin">
                                <label style="display:inline-table;">
                                    <span>{{ form_widget(form.id) }}</span>
                                </label>
                            </section>
                            <section class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9"style="position: relative; left: 5vmin;top: 6vmin">
                                <label style="display:inline-table;">
                                    <span>{{ form_widget(form.libelle) }}</span>
                                </label>
                            </section>
                            <section class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9" style="position: relative; left: 5vmin;top: 6vmin">
                                <label style="display:inline-table;">
                                    <span>{{form_widget(form.idprof, {attr: { value : profil.id}} )}}</span>
                                </label>
                            </section>
                            <section class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5" style="position: relative; left: 5vmin;top: 6vmin">
                                <span>{{ form_widget(form.Edit)  }}</span>
                            </section>
                            {{ form_end(form) }}


 {{ form_start(form2, { attr: {novalidate: 'novalidate'} }) }}
                <section class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9" style="position: relative; left: 5vmin;top: 6vmin">
                    <label style="display:inline-table;">
                        <span>{{ form_widget(form2.id) }}</span>
                    </label>
                </section>
                <section class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9"style="position: relative; left: 5vmin;top: 6vmin">
                    <label style="display:inline-table;">
                        <span>{{ form_widget(form2.libelle) }}</span>
                    </label>
                </section>
                <section class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5" style="position: relative; left: 5vmin;top: 6vmin">
                    <span>{{ form_widget(form2.Ajouter)  }}</span>
                </section>
                {{ form_end(form2) }}
```

Comment: do you get any errors? Also, you don't need this for both forms if ($request->request->has('form')) since you're checking the form is submitted and valid.

Comment: ah ok :) i checked the profiler it shows that: the form was not submitted.

Comment: can you post generated html for both forms?

Comment: do u mean what's written in the twig file?? i've already posted it

Comment: I mean what you are getting in the browser. I want to see what the names of the forms.

Comment: Yup each form has exactly the "title" and the placeholder that i wrote it for it

Comment: What's the value of name attribute of each form? i.e <form name="some-name">

Comment: its 'form' and 'form2' like its written in my code :  {{ form_start(form2, { attr: {novalidate: 'novalidate'} }) }} and  {{ form_start(form, { attr: {novalidate: 'novalidate'} }) }}

Comment: ok, next thing I'd recommend to check is what is actually being sent to the server. You can use chrome developer tools (network tab) for that or simply var_dump($request->getContent()) and check whether the data is actually there.

Comment: the var_dump returned the same data i wrote in the form2 fields :string(59) "form%5Bid%5D=11&form%5Blibelle%5D=sdfghj&form%5BAjouter%5D="

Comment: if that's the request when you submitted form2 then that's your problem. in this request form is beeing submitted, not form2. Still look at the form names. Your form2 is rendered with name="form" attribiute.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I'd recommend removing form classes from the controller and putting them in a separate classes under Form folder of your bundle.
Then in this classes give them different prefixes to this forms.

```
public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'form1';
    }
```

Then, name all the form fields correctly and you won't have to apply data to each entity field manually.
Also remove this line for both forms.

```
$request-request->has('form')
```

Why are you using $em->merge instead of persist while submitting form. Or maybe I'm missing something?
Try reading this documentation.
http://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html
Symfony has really great documentation.

Comment: i used merge in edit, because as what i've learned, it allows me to edit just one field and to add its data, but i think persist will create a new ligne in the database with that data

Comment: no it won't if it exists in the db, i.e. entity with the same id is already in db.

Comment: in form folder i already have a class ProfilType , so  i add that getBlockPrefix function in it??

Comment: Yes. And you'll also have to replace forms from your controller to next $this->createForm(ProfilType::class, $profil)

Comment: then if this function just returns 'form1' or "form2" will this work for both forms????

Comment: sure if you create different formType classes. From your code above it looks like the forms are different.

Comment: but i still have one or two other forms to be handled in this action, i don't think creating so many classes for the same type of forms is a good practice and will solve my issue

Comment: I'm giving you the approach I use an it works fine. It's up to you how to do it.

Comment: Okay i created two form classes ; EditType and AddType, and in each one there is a function that returns its name, then in the controller i create my form like this :  $form = $this->get('form.factory')->createBuilder(EditType::class,$profil, array('csrf_protection' => false))  But i got an error : Could not load type "CNAMCMSBundle\Form\EditType"  (I've declared the class with a use a statement)

Comment: please, follow these tutorials http://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#creating-form-classes

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by adding the method post to my second form :

```
  $form2 = $this->createFormBuilder($profile,array('csrf_protection' => false))
                ->setMethod("POST");
```